# When is $0^0 = 1$ inconvenient? I heard sometimes $0^0 = 0$ may help.

Tags: exponentiation, integers

Don't get me wrong: my question is NOT claiming $0^0 = 1$. I understand it's indeterminate.

Many articles show that defining $0^0 = 1$ is (just) convenient and I completely agree. However, I've heard something like "yeah, $0^0 = 1$ is convenient in integer and real but sometimes it's more reasonable to use $0^0 = 0$ especially in complex ..."

Can anybody show me any case where $0^0 = 0$ (or something else, other than 1) is more convenient?

Comment: $0^0$ is totally just equal to $1$. I don't know of any situation where the better convention is that $0^0 = 0$.

Comment: Maybe when $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{+}}0^x$

Comment: The plot of $y=x^x$ also showcases how $0^0$ is best defined as $1$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm replying too late but you are absolutely wrong, if you consider $0^0 = 0/0$ by definition.

Comment: Or at least blindly thinking so is wrong. Note that I also think that setting $0^0 = 1$ is convenient, but it's just convenient.